# wrapAll unchecks checked radio button in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a code like this:

```
var root="<div id=\"editorIdPrefix01e36f3a6d53541512468193877\" contenteditable=\"true\"></div>";
var kid = "<div>" + 
  "<input name=\"fieldControlId2\" id=\"fieldId2_1\" type=\"radio\" checked=\"checked\" value=\"1\">" + 
  "<input name=\"fieldControlId2\" id=\"fieldId2_2\" type=\"radio\" value=\"2\">" +
"</div>";
var result = $(kid).wrapAll($(root)).parent();
alert(result.find("input").first().prop("outerHTML"));
```

Notice: there is input with `checked="checked"` inside the `kid` variable. In internet explorer 11 after wrapping the input is being unchecked. Any idea what's going on (works ok in chrome/ff) ?

JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/svejdo1/81dc0gg4/2/

**EDIT**
Thanks for the comments, but the `checked="checked"` is being created automatically via various jQuery manipulations (i.e. if you use jquery to `append` `<input checked />` to some parent element, it automatically changes to `checked="checked"`

Also experimentally changing the root to

```
var root="<div id=\"editorIdPrefix01e36f3a6d53541512468193877\"></div>";
```

Fixes the issue, so at this point I suspect jQuery bug.

Comment: .wrapAll is meant to create a new element and place the selected elements within it. you are passing an existing element into it instead. Try to use append instead of wrapAll

Comment: Possible explanation is the different ways in which properties such as checked and hidden have been dealt with over the years. I think that old IE wanted something like `<input CHECKED/>` (with caps) whereas Chrome and FF at the time wanted `<input checked="checked"/>`. However, I think the consistent 'correct' one in HTML5 is `<input checked>`.

Comment: `checked` is a boolean attribute. `cheked="checked"` isn't valid in HTML5. Just set it as `checked`: `type=\"radio\" checked placeholder=\"fieldPlaceholder2\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is a known IE 11 serialization issue. Sample here:

```js
var root = document.getElementById('editor');
var kid1 = document.getElementById('kid1');
var kid2 = document.getElementById('kid2');
root.appendChild(kid1);
root.appendChild(kid2);
alert(root.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" data-ckeditor="true"></div>
<div>
  <input name="fieldControlId2" id="kid1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1">
  <input name="fieldControlId2" id="kid2" type="radio" value="2">
</div>
```

Solution is easy, before manipulating the nodes run fixup for IE11:

```
if (isIe11()) {
  $(kid).find('input[checked="checked"]').each(function() {
    $(this)[0].setAttribute("checked");
  });
}
```